# The border-image-source property showing black border with linear gredient

Tags: css, border

I have added the white color linear gradient with less opacity for the border but it is showing the black border.

```css
.input-field {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 18px 28px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  background: linear-gradient(126.6deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12) 28.69%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  backdrop-filter: blur(140px);
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(123.98deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 127.65%),linear-gradient(268.18deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) -17.36%, rgba(239, 239, 239, 0) 15.78%);
}
```

```html
<input type="email" class="input-field" placeholder="Name">
```

Comment: Can you help me understand what are you expecting this to look like? Thanks.

Comment: Use  your browser's dev tools inspect facility. You will see that the border-image value is invalid CSS so it isn't being applied at all.